Sagemaker / Athena -- urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
I need to engineer features for a large dataset (1.5 billion transactions), processing it in batches. The batch size is determined by a time window (e.g., 100,000 seconds). Everything runs smoothly until the 49th batch, where it fails with the error below. Interestingly, this same process worked without issues three weeks ago, and it continues to run perfectly for other datasets. Here's a snippet of the error log (the full log is too large to include).
I'm trying to understand why this issue is occurring now.
A little about the system: i am running the script in Sagemaker, the script inside is querying Athena.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 411, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir, ca_cert_data)
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 465, in send
    urllib_response = conn.urlopen(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 802, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 527, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 716, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 404, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1061, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 419, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 413, in ssl_wrap_socket
    raise SSLError(e)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
...
...
log_continues
...
...
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://athena.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ [Errno 24] Too many open files
[2024-09-05 13:51:24,299][23910][ERROR] datalake.query: failed to execute query: SELECT "transaction_date" "datetime", ... FROM "lesaka"."raw_trxs_v5" WHERE ("transaction_date">=CAST('2023-03-01 00:40:00.000' AS TIMESTAMP) AND "transaction_date"<CAST('2023-03-02 04:26:40.000' AS TIMESTAMP)) ..., throws SSL validation failed for https://athena.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ [Errno 24] Too many open files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 411, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir, ca_cert_data)
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Originally i tried with a much larger time window for each batch (on a much larger Sagemaker instance), but the script would just end abruptly after a few hours, with a memory issue.
I reduced the time window for each batch and the I got OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy, which is related to Athena taking some time to build the connection. Putting a retry mechanism over that line solved the issue, but now i am getting the error I mentioned, and i have no idea how to proceed with it.

error already says there are too many open files meaning you have hit the limit of open files in sagemaker. SageMaker instances usually have a limit on the number of open files. You can check this limit by running:
ulimit -n

Increase the limit if the limit is too low, you can attempt to increase it by running:
ulimit -n 4096  # or a higher number if needed

you may need to adjust this in your instance configuration, or ensure that the limit is increased for your SageMaker notebook or script.
There are several reason behind you hitting the limit of open files please make sure to look into followings to optimize:

how to close connection after every query
connection pooling
retry logic and throttling
tuning batch size
time out settings in athena
monitoring the open files

